# How to setup Maya 2016 and PyCharm Community Edition 2017 IDE

Tags: python, scripting, pycharm, maya, pymel

Been trying for 8 hours now to get pycharm to work with mayapy.exe but i just cant get it to work.
From clean installs of both programs i first open an empty scene in maya. Then i open pycharm and add mayapy.exe as interpreter and what automaticly gets selected there. 
[Pycharm interpretor setup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD62a.png)
Then i test with:

```
import pymel.core as pm
pm.polyCube()
```

but nothing happens, it gives exit code 0

```
import pymel.core as pm
pm.polyCube()
Print("hello")
```

Prints hello but doesnt create a cube in maya.

While if i use that code in maya it works.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: the author of MayaCharm hangs out on http://tech-artists.org/ and its associated slack channel

Answer (score 0):

adding mayapy won't do anything in maya, if you using mayapy you need to use maya standalone module. But in your case you just need to setup commandport properly, [Mayacharm](https://github.com/cmcpasserby/MayaCharm) or some same kind [toolset](http://www.emeraldartist.com/remotely-execute-code-in-maya-using-pycharm/) can help you

Comment: Thanks Achayan. 
I just solved it by adding commandport code to userSetup.py.

Comment: What about the auto-completion? How to setup the devkit?